# undefined reference error, assigning a value to a vector of char vectors by passing a classes function? c++

Tags: c++

I'm not even sure if that's the right way to phrase my question. basically I have a class Game, and I'm trying to do something like:

```
Game game;
std::vector< std::vector<char> > gameBoard;
gameBoard = game.initVector(rows,rowSize);
```

and in game.hpp:

```
class Game{
public:
Game();
//method to initialize the start vector
std::vector< std::vector<char> > initVector(int rows, int rowSize);
...}
```

and when I try to link I'm getting the following error:

```
...test-game.cpp:15: undefined reference to 'Game::initVector(int,int)'
```

What's happening here? How do I eliminate this?

Comment: [See this question.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: Learn to prepare a [minimal complete example](http://www.sscce.org), and you'll see most of the mystery of these problems vanish before your eyes.